# Failing to trigger the onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, search, onchange

I've got this piece of code, to search the contents of HTML elements with the class "widget" and use the jQuery functions `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` to only show elements that match the search term. I don't know how to assign the search function to, because I don't assign it to the search box's change event. What is the equal of `onchange=` in jQuery? My current code:

```
function search(text, elements) {
    var term = text.value.toLowerCase();
    var elms = $(elements);
    var elm;
    for (var i = elms.length; i > 0; i-=1){
        elm = elms.get(i);
        if (elm.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term)>=0 ) {
            elm.fadeOut(500);
        } else {
            elm.fadeIn(500);
        }

    }
}
```

And the failing inline script to trigger the onchange:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").change(function() {
            search($("#search").text(),".widget");
        });
    });
```

Comment: `.change(function(){...})` (or `.on("change",function(){...})`) _is_ how you assign an `onchange` handler with jQuery. But if you want your function to be called with each keystroke use `.keyup()` instead because `onchange` (with or without jQuery) only fires when you leave the field. Although I don't think I'd use a 500ms animation with every keystroke.

Comment: I agree with nnnnnn however, I responded with what I've been caught with as well with jQuery. Binding to onchange and expecting it to be keyup. Not really a "gotcha" but, I've made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use keyup() instead of change, Change only fires on blur.

Answer (score 0):

> $("#search").change(function() {
>       search($("#search").text(),".widget");
>     });

.change() is a reference to the .on() function in JQuery, so if you would like you could rewrite it this way :

> $("#search").on('change' , function(){
>       search($(this).val(),".widget");
>     });